# Effect of speed of turbo fan in bypass jet engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, applied-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, jet

Why do we keep speed of turbofan of turbofan jet engine, low.

And what is the maximum thrust a turbofan jet engine., how much can thrust a turbofan jet engine produce with just compressed air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fan speed is kept low because the blades in it must not exceed the speed of sound during operation, otherwise the efficiency of the fan will go down and noise generation will go up.

I am not sure your second question is meaningful; all jet engines generate thrust by discharging a large mass flow rate of compressed air from their tailpipes. They compress that air by burning fuel and capturing some of the heat energy thus produced in a turbine which then spins the compressor.

Comment: i wanted to ask following through second question - can i not introduce heat using fuel and just compress the air using axial compressor, normally air is compressed there and then fuel is injected, my question is can i still produce thrust without injection of fuel, with just compressed air. There will obviously be some source of energy to power the compressor.

Comment: yes, you can. I suggest you study the thermodynamic process of the *brayton cycle* for more useful insights on this.